# thread pool starvation definition

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, clr

According to this article(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vancem/diagnosing-net-core-threadpool-starvation-with-perfview-why-my-service-is-not-saturating-all-cores-or-seems-to-stall?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003493), we can recognize thread pool starvation by observing
'Windows Kernel/Thread/Start' event in PerfView.

I've created a simple endpoint:

```
namespace Test
{
    [Route("test")]
    [ApiController]
    public class MaintenanceController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Test()
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
            return NoContent();
        }
    }
}
```

The endpoint was hit by West Wind Web Surge with the following settings:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTvc2.png)

When I take a look at Perfview when WWWS is done, I see events that should indicate thread pool starvation:

[PerfView pool starvation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WviNU.png)

I don't understand why I see such events? Is it really thread pool starvation or not?

Comment: *async* specifically avoids starvation, try it with Thread.Sleep() instead.

Comment: why would I do that? i want to avoid starvation, but cannot even on this simple example.

Comment: This simple example does not have a starvation problem.  So you won't see the pattern described it the linked article.  So the only problem here is that you don't have a problem.

Comment: :) the article explicitly says that when I see 'Windows Kernel/Thread/Start" event emitted, it is about thread starvation.according to you, how should I recognize starvation problem ?